# jQuery Tools - make tabs collapsible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

I'm using a basic integration of **jQuery Tools** "tabs" function and it's working perfectly for me, but the one thing it seems to lack over jQueryUI is that there's no way I can find to make the tabs collapsible. By that I mean all you need to add is

```
collapsible:true
```

to the jQueryUI tabs function.

Does anyone know of a way I could append code  to the following jQuery Tools statement to make the tabs collapsible?

Any advice appreciated!

```
$("ul.main_tabs").tabs("> .mainpane");
```

Comment: Unless there was a recent change, this was never added as an option on their tabs, so there's not a way without changing the plugin itself.

Comment: Was afraid someone would say that...!

Is there any hack I could put in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/25/53211#post-53223

Comment: $('ul.main_tabs a').click(function() {
  var api = $('.ul.main_tabs').data('tabs');
  if (api.getIndex() == $(this).parent('li').index()) {
   api.getCurrentPane().slideToggle();
   api.getCurrentTab().toggleClass('current');
  }
 });